# Iterating through two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_1 = {'H1':[0,1,3,2],
          'H2':[5,4,2,1,5],
          'H3':[1,2,5]}

dict_2 = {'H1':[[1,4,3,2],
                [6,5,3,2],
                [1,4,3,2]],
          'H2':[[0,0,1,6,3],
                [2,1,4,2,1],
                [5,1,2,5,3]],
          'H3':[[2,3,4],
                [2,1,4],
                [0,1,2]]}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the items in the values of the keys in dict_1, and check if any of those items are in any of the items in the values of the corresponding key in dict_2. Then print the value, and the index where it was found in the key of dict_2.

So for example, because 0 in the list of the key 'H1' of dict_1 isn't found in any of the lists of the key 'H1' in dict 2, nothing would be printed. Now if we check for 1, then

```
1, 'H1', 0, # because there is a one in the first list of 'H1' of dict_2
1, 'H1', 2, # because there is a one in the 3rd list of 'H1' of dict_2
```

here `1` corresponds to the item that was checked for, `'H1'`  the key that was checked, and `0`, and `2` represent which list the `1` was found in in dict_2

this is what I have:

```
for i in range(3):
    for k,v in dict_1.items():
        for x,y in dict_2.items():
            if k == x:
                for j in v:
                    if j in y[i]:
                        print j,x,i
```

But I'm wondering if this will take care of everything, or if it will print repeated items?

Comment: *"I'm wondering if this will take everything, or if it will print repeated items"* - then... run it and find out? Why are you asking us, rather than **testing it?**

Comment: The answers proposed thus far all take the approach of searching the sub-lists linearly. As a result, their overall time performance will be O(N * M), where N is the total number of values in `dict_1`, and M is the average length of the sub-lists in `dict_2`. For small sets, this will be okay. For very large data, especially N, consider using a `dict()` to pre-compute part of the answers. This would have O(N + Q) time, where Q would be the total number of items in sub-lists in `dict_2`. (Q would be >> M, so it mainly makes sense when N becomes large, and especially with duplicates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for key, d1_list in dict_1.iteritems():
    for element in d1_list:
        for ind, d2_list in enumerate(dict_2[key]):
            if element in d2_list:
                print element, key, ind
```

Iterate over all the key, and lists and d1.  Then over element in d1_list, and finally check if it's any any of the lists in dict_2 corresponding to the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers first: yes, your code will "take care of everything", and will not "print repeated items" meaning that if a value is appearing several time in the same list in dict_2, than it will be spotted only once by your code.

Executing your code on those dict demonstrates this:

```
dict_1 = {'H1':[0,1,3,2]}

dict_2 = {'H1':[[0,0],
            [1,2]]}

for i in range(2):
    for k,v in dict_1.items():
        for x,y in dict_2.items():
            if k == x:
                for j in v:
                    if j in y[i]:
                        print j,x,i
```

Output is:

```
0 H1 0
1 H1 1
2 H1 1
```

Hence spotting only once the 0 value while appearing twice in first sublist in dict_2.

Now, to complete the same objective, we can simplify a little your code, given that:

- you want to compare only the same keys in the two dicts
- you may want to have different size of list in dict_2

I would propose the following:

```
# Loop on all key values in dict_1
for k,v in dict_1.items():
    # Loop only on values in dict_2 for same key
    for i,y in enumerate(dict_2[k]):
        # Loop over values in first list
        for j in v:
            # Assert existence in second list
            if j in y:
                # Display result if found (note that index of subblist in dict_2 is retrieved through enumerate function
                print j,x,i
```

This output the exact same result with additional lisibility and flexibility for dict_2 format.

Hope this helps.